# Following Path Bone Jumps at the end of the path

Tags: path

When I select the bone, then Path, then <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> Follow Path the bone goes straight to the end of the path.

I tried Clear origin, parent, offset etc etc but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it... I did a parenting from the bone to the mesh with Keep Transform...